# Not able to run mysql query through batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to run a dos script to execute the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump --opt --where='1 limit 1'  -h a.b.c.d  -u root -proot remotedb remotetable|mysql -u root -pcanada localdb
```

I am not able to run this script.If I do not put double quotes around the path it gives error as 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
If I put double quotes around the path then also it fails with following error:
"mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'limit' when selecting the database"

Could anyone suggest how I could run this query in script.It runs perfect when i run it directly through command line.Problem comes when i try to run it through batch ie .cmd file.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump" --opt --where="1 limit 1" -h a.b.c.d -u root -proot remotedb remotetable
```

You have to quote the path because it contains spaces and `cmd` doesn't treat single quotes as anything special.

Comment: actually i also added double quote after mysqldump then it worked:"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump" --opt --where="1 limit 1"  -h 54.241.136.44  -u root -proot salebuild_ctl autoconfirm|mysql -u root -pcanada salebuild_ctl